# Update data when other user input data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am wondering what is the best way to grab data when some other user insert the data automatically without refreshing? 
It seems like socket will be too far fetch since everyone online will be in the same socket. I know I can set it to `setInterval()` to 1000 or something but is there a better way to grab data when other user insert the data?

For example, in stack overflow you get a unread post without refreshing when other user post a question. Does stack overflow `setInterval()` every `x` seconds? or is there a more efficient way to do this?

Thank you

Comment: From my opinion the only approach is what you have mentioned already, you have to use web sockets to make a connection between the front and the back end, so when the back end is changed it send the request to the front end to change its state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement it using normal Ajax (Ajax polling) but, web-socket is the way to go and its there because Ajax based solutions was to some extent not good at scaling and they use some much resources per request those are some articles that can guide through and you can decide based on what you see fit for your App:

- [websockets vs long polling](https://www.ably.io/blog/websockets-vs-long-polling/)
- [long polling vs websockets vs server sent events](https://medium.com/system-design-blog/long-polling-vs-websockets-vs-server-sent-events-c43ba96df7c1)